# Cifar100 only has 16 training images and 16 training labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, python-3.7

I'm using Tensorflow with Python 3.7, and I am trying to make an image classifier with CIFAR-100. I want to stay away from Keras as much as possible because it only has a limited amount of datasets that I can use. This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL.Image as Image
from tensorflow import keras

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

shape = (224, 224)

labels = '/home/pi/tf/cifar_labels.txt'
labels = np.array(open(labels).read().splitlines())

img = '/home/pi/tf/lobster.jpeg'
img = Image.open(img).resize(shape)
img = np.array(img)/255.0
img = np.reshape(img, (224, 224, 3))

train = tfds.load(name="cifar100", split="train")
test = tfds.load(name="cifar100", split="test")

train = train.shuffle(1024).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
test = test.shuffle(1024).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

for features in train:
    train_images, train_labels = features["image"], features["label"]

for features in test:
    test_images, test_labels = features["image"], features["label"]

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=200, verbose=2)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)

print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

I'm guessing that there is something wrong with the `for features in train` for loop. When I print the `len` of the training images/labels, I get 16. Due to this, my model is getting a training accuracy of 0% and a loss of 16.1181%. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use CIFAR-100 in your keras model directly you should call tfds.load function with `as_supervised=True` parameter. It will then load the dataset with only 'image' and 'label' keys. [You can see that CIFAR-100 dataset contains three keys](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/cifar100):

```
FeaturesDict({
    'coarse_label': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=20),
    'image': Image(shape=(32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.uint8),
    'label': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=100),
})
```

Therefore it cannot be fed into `model.fit()` directly. With `as_supervised` set as True, the returned dataset will only contain `(u'image', u'label')` keys.

To sum up,

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow import keras

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

train= tfds.load(name="cifar100", split="train", as_supervised=True)
test = tfds.load(name="cifar100", split="test", as_supervised=True)


train = train.shuffle(1024).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
test = test.shuffle(1024).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train, epochs=200, verbose=1)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test, verbose=1)

print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

Note:
To use the dataset without as_supervised set to True, you can use model.train_on_batch function. e.g.

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow import keras

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

train= tfds.load(name="cifar100", split="train")
test = tfds.load(name="cifar100", split="test")


train = train.shuffle(1024).repeat(200).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
test = test.shuffle(1024).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

for epoch in range(200):
  for features in train:
    image_batch, label_batch = features["image"], features["label"]
    loss, acc = model.train_on_batch(image_batch, label_batch)

for features in test:
  image_batch, label_batch = features["image"], features["label"]
  loss, acc = model.test_on_batch(image_batch, label_batch)
```